# about reading a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

when I try to read a file, there is a strange outcome described as the following

the code is

```
f1=file('u1.base')
for line in f1.readlines()[0:5]:
print line    
train=f1.readlines()
f2=file('u1.test')
test=f2.readlines()
l_train=len(train)
l_test=len(test)
print l_train,l_test
```

the outcome is

```
1   1   5   874965758

1   2   3   876893171

1   3   4   878542960

1   4   3   876893119

1   5   3   889751712

0 20000
```

which shows that the the length of train is 0. I don't know the reason. Hope you can help me~

Comment: First of all your code has lost proper indentation and cannot be deciphered unambiguously, fix this. Second: how many lines are in u1.base? You're reading all of them in "f1.readlines()[0:5]"

Answer (score 1):

The first `f1.readlines()` reads all lines (file position is at the end of file). The second `f1.readlines()` immediately encounters EOF and returns empty list. You could call `f1.seek(0)` to move the file position to the beginning of the file.

To read only 5 lines:

```
from itertools import islice

for line in islice(f1, 5):
    print line,
```

Comment: Or if you're going to read the whole file into memory, only do it once and print the first 5 lines after you do it.

Comment: @Wooble: `islice(f1, 5)` reads only 5 lines. It doesn't read all file into memory. If you are talking about `f1.readlines()` then "reads all lines" in the answer strongly implies that the whole file is read into memory.

Comment: I mean that the OP is planning to read the whole file into memory anyway after printing the first 5 lines, so there's no real reason to read the first 5 lines once and then read them again immediately afterwards.

Comment: I don't know about you, but I've always preferred `sys.stdout.write(str(line))` to `print line,`.  Maybe that's just my tastes though...